# scrreprt problem: \rm command found but already removed

Tags: texmaker, bibliographystyle, scrreprt

I'm writing my thesis in Texmaker and using a "nested" document, where each chapter (.tex) is loaded individually in the main .tex file. The bibliography file is, as usual, a .bib file (Bib(la)Tex=biber).

When I print the bibliography at the end of the document with this command at line 118:

```
l117       %% insert bibliography, adds chapter heading with chapter number   
l118       \printbibliography  
l119     
l120       \end{document}
```

I get either: `"Line 119 :  ! Class scrreprt Error: undefined old font command '\rm'. See the scrreprt class documentation for explanation. Type H <return> for immediate help...."`

or a bunch of individual single parenthesis/$ symbols allegedly missing in the .bib file.
Since 2 days ago was all right, then I added an entry in the .bib which had this old '\rm' command into it.

Now:

a) there is no more any '\rm' command in my .bib file. All removed.

b) I checked all the .bib file and I can ensure there is no $ nor '{' missing whatsoever.

c) How to know exactly what/where it refers to in the .bib file? Where can I type "H" or "2" in Texmaker to get the help he wants to give me?

Comment: Delete the bbl file and recompile from scratch.

Comment: You could type `H` if you compiled on the command line, when you hit the compile button in Texmaker you can't use this. The help text wouldn't have told you where this was encountered anyways, it would've been an explanation of the reasoning why `\rm` don't work in KOMA-script classes.